# TSQL - Missing Month

Tags: sql-server

I need to find the missing months in a table 
for the earliest and latest start dates per ID_No.  As an example:

```
create table #InputTable (ID_No int ,OccurMonth datetime)

insert into #InputTable (ID_No,OccurMonth) 
select 10, '2007-11-01' Union all
select 10, '2007-12-01' Union all
select 10, '2008-01-01' Union all
select 20, '2009-01-01' Union all
select 20, '2009-02-01' Union all
select 20, '2009-04-01' Union all
select 30, '2010-05-01' Union all
select 30, '2010-08-01' Union all
select 30, '2010-09-01' Union all
select 40, '2008-03-01'
```

For the above table, the answer should be:

```
ID_No   OccurMonth

-----   ---------- 

20      2009-02-01 

30      2010-06-01 

30      2010-07-01
```

The other solutions posted on this site are similar, but:
    1) don't include an ID column,
    2) don't use the start date/end dates in the data or
    3) use cursors, which are forbidden in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH
    MonthRange AS 
    (
        SELECT      ID_No,
                    MinMonth = MIN(OccurMonth),
                    MaxMonth = MAX(OccurMonth)
        FROM        #InputTable
        GROUP BY    ID_No
    ),
    AllMonths AS
    (
        SELECT      ID_No, 
                    OccurMonth = MinMonth
        FROM        MonthRange
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      a.ID_No,
                    DATEADD(MONTH, 1, a.OccurMonth)
        FROM        AllMonths       a
        INNER JOIN  MonthRange      r   ON a.ID_No = r.ID_No
        WHERE       a.OccurMonth < r.MaxMonth
    )


SELECT      a.*
FROM        AllMonths       a
LEFT JOIN   #InputTable     i   ON a.ID_No = i.ID_No
                                AND a.OccurMonth = i.OccurMonth
WHERE       i.ID_No IS NULL
OPTION      (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

`AllMonths` is a recursive CTE that lists out all months between the min and max month for each `ID_no`. Then it's only a simple `LEFT JOIN` to find what month is missing in between.